# How can my code identify the mode passed to fopen() if it's only passed a FILE*?

Tags: c, file, fopen

Suppose my function accepts a `FILE*` and it would like to know how exactly the underlying file was open - specifically which `mode` (such as for example `r` or `rb`) was passed into `fopen()`.

How can my code find which value `mode` had if it's only passed a `FILE*` of an already opened file?

Comment: I imagine there is no platform-independent way. But why would you be in such a situation?

Answer (score 5):

On Unix-like systems, you can use `fcntl(fileno(fp), F_GETFL, &flags)` to retrieve the flags of the underlying file descriptor. Use the `O_ACCMODE` mask to obtain the file access mode, which is one of `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, `O_RDWRD` and `O_APPEND` values corresponding to mode strings passed to `fopen`.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, on linux, you can use `fcntl()` to achieve this. Man page [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html).

However, you'll be needing the corresponding `fd` [maybe with `fileno()`], because, `fcntl()` does not work directly with `FILE *`.

In this case, if you use `F_GETFL` to read the `File status flags`, it will return you the status of the flags, which can be used to determine the `mode` of that file pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no portable way to do this.

What you can do, although it's of course *fantastically ugly and quite scary*, is to use [`fileno()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fileno) to get the underlying file descriptor, and then use [`fdopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) to re-open the file using the mode you want.